# What is the difference between "objects" and "abstract data types"? When do you use which?

Tags: oop, object, abstract-data-type

## Context

[This essay](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) goes into detail describing "objects" and "abstract data types" (ADT) (and [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/OOPvsADT/CookOOPvsADT90.pdf) is an older explanation by the same author)

Here is an excerpt:

> Despite 25 years of research, there is still
>   widespread confusion about *the* two forms of data abstraction,
>   abstract data types and objects. This essay attempts to
>   explain the differences and also why the differences matter.
>
> The typical response is a variant of
>   “objects are a kind of abstract data type”.
>   This response is consistent with most programming language
>   textbooks. [... But] the textbooks are
>   wrong! Objects and abstract data types are not the same
>   thing, and neither one is a variation of the other. They are
>   fundamentally different and in many ways complementary,
>   in that the strengths of one are the weaknesses of the other.
>   The issues are obscured by the fact that most modern programming
>   languages support both objects and abstract data
>   types, often blending them together into one syntactic form.
>   But syntactic blending does not erase fundamental semantic
>   differences which affect flexibility, extensibility, safety and
>   performance of programs. Therefore, to use modern programming
>   languages effectively, one should understand the
>   fundamental difference between objects and abstract data
>   types.

## Question

Is there a concise explanation using modern, non-academic language examples? (If not, it would be great if someone provided one here or I might write my own answer when I have the time)

Of particular interest are the definitions and distinctions between objects and ADT's, and practical implications when writing code (or designing a language).

## Caveat

*I strongly recommend looking at the linked essay before commenting or answering.*

Here is an example of type of insight I am looking for, also excerpted from the essay:

> Abstract data types define operations that collect together the behaviors for a given action. Objects organize the matrix the other way, collecting together all the actions associated with a given representation. It is easier to add new operations in an ADT, and new representations using objects. [...] Object-oriented programs can use inheritance to add new operations.

Note that at least as far as the essay is concerned, as of Jan 3, 2014, **Wikipedia is wrong** (or at least incomplete) and **so are most textbooks**. The essay was written by a *computer science professor* after noticing the lack of understanding of these concepts, even *among his academic peers*.

Comment: This is an elementary OOP concept. Are you currently taking a class, self teaching yourself, or are prepping for a class in the future?

Comment: [See Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type): Essentially they are blueprints to represent a mathematical model (theoretically). They provide values and functions for a specific data type. p.s. This may be too broad and opinionated.

Comment: I think it should be an elementary concept taught in early classes...but I've yet to see a good, concise explanation on the internet after looking for hours. See the linked paper for some of the nuances. The wikipedia explanation doesn't even acknowledge objects as a form of data abstraction. I'm mainly interested in having a solid resource I can refer people to. For reference, I've taken and taught many programming classes and have yet to see this explicitly discussed.

Comment: I flagged this post suggesting a move and the move was declined. I can manually copy it over...

Comment: This question isn't "too broad", just uncomfortable for some. And, no, it isn't a good fit for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It doesn't help that the most popular object-oriented languages (Java and the like) provide neither pure ADTs nor pure objects, but rather a hybrid between them. Programmers who "learn by doing" end up not understanding the distinction,because they are never confronted with it.

Comment: @gnat I think you are referring to a comment that no longer exists (not deleted by me, though). Moreover a comment that, if it existed at all, was posted over two years ago, back before the site was rebranded (including a change in scope and target audience descriptions). So I hope you're just being funny. ^.^